# What is the difference between loading a background file or a data file onto a Trimble unit?

Tags: trimble

I am curious what the difference is between loading a background file and a data file onto a Trimble in Terrasync, as both seem to be able to display a .shp file.

Is it that a data file can then be edited while in the field but a background file can not?

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes - a data file can be opened for editing while a background file cannot.  Also, background file can be an image - like a scanned topo map or aerial imagery.

You can also use a data file as a background if you want to - but you won't be able to view any of the attributes for the features while it is being used as a background.

Comment: I would like to add that at least based off my experience, i would avoid loading data files in the background if they are also accessible as project files (i.e. in the datalogger). TerraSync seems to get unstable after a while.